# Difference between StackFrame and MethodBase when using in Logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging, stack-trace

I have seen two separate codes that use the StackFrame and MethodBase when implementing Logging in.NET.

I know that `MethodBase` class provides information about methods and constructors, and where they come from. The `StackFrame` represents a function call on the call stack for the current thread

**The first code uses the StackFrame:**

```
StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, false);
var method = frame.GetMethod();
var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;

return LogManager.GetLogger(declaringType);
```

**The second code uses the MethodBase:**

```
var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var declaringTye = method.DeclaringType;
return LogManager.GetLogger(declaringTye);
```

Why would the first code be used and not the second code, vice-versa? In my own experience, I know that using the first code will cause an issue when you're in the release mode of your application, thus require some changes. Something like the below.

```
do
{
   StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, false);
   var method = frame.GetMethod();
   var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;
   if (declaringType == null)
   {
       loggerName = method.Name;
       break;
   }
   framesToSkip++;
   loggerName = declaringType.FullName;
} while (declaringType.Module.Name.Equals("mscorlib.dll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
return LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCurrentMethod` won't allow you to call up the stack. Some logging implementations like to skip any internals for the logging system to make the logs more relevant.